# Drawing/Moving/Deleting strokes on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas, drawing

I am developing a drawing app using HTML5 Cordova.

I need to implement drawing ,move strokes, delete ink strokes on HTML5 Canvas.

I am exploring best ways to achieve the following:

1) Draw a stroke
2) Select a stroke and move it
3) Select a stroke and delete it.

It would be something similar to this:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/touch-drawing-app-using-html5-canvas

But I need to select/move/delete strokes which is not supported in above library.

Any pointers/samples would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Html canvas drawings cannot be moved or deleted--they are permanent. Instead you must clear the canvas and redraw any desired content in its "moved" position (or not redraw content to "delete" that content).

Comment: When you want a more object-oriented approach to graphic compositing, you might look into SVG where every image element is an object you can manipulate after placing it in the SVG document..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 canvas works like a canvas in real-life. When you draw a line on a piece of paper, the only way to change it afterwards is to erase it with an eraser (potentially also damaging something else drawn there) or draw something over it which covers it. When you draw something to a HTML5 canvas, it stops being an object and becomes a bunch of pixels on the canvas. You can only manipulate it afterwards by overdrawing.

When you want the user to modify strokes they drew before, you need to save all the strokes the user made to an array. When the user makes a change to a stroke, you need to erase and redraw the whole canvas from scratch.

When you are dealing a lot with geometrical objects which the user can move around freely, you might also consider to use SVG as an alternative. In SVG every image element is an object you can manipulate after placing it in the SVG document.

Comment: Thanks for your response and descriptive answer.